# Android Studio: how to check if I have code which calls functions/properties not available in minSdkVersion?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wonder how to check if I have code which calls functions/properties not available in minSdkVersion.

For example, I want to avoid to call a function available only in API 25 in an app designed for API 15 and higher.

I would like to get easily a list of all the places where this kind of error happens.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Analyze -> Inspect code in Android Studio.
Look into Android>Lint>Correctness in "Calling new methods on older version" section.

Comment: Thanks. I have got (in the scroll bar of the Android Studio editor) the warning 'Field requires API level 16 (current min is 15)' on 'notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;' but I don't manage to find this warning in Lint... No 'Calling new methods on older version' section in Android>Lint>Correctness :( Do you know where I can find this warning in Lint?

Comment: @Regis_AG In your case it will be other section in Lint>Correctness - http://take.ms/ewdru

Comment: Ok, found it... In Correctness => 'Using inline constants on older versions'... Not easy to have a global view and simple list of this kind of problems... It should not be possible to submit an app when these problems exist. They should be considered as errors and not just warnings. Thanks for your help.